# How to match and diff timestamps in log and error when no end timestamp appear?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm new to Apache Spark and I'm looking for a Java example to do the following:

I have a log file with lines like this:

```
 ...timestamp...[id:1234]..START...
 ...
 ...timestamp...[id:1234]..END...
```

- The timestamps are of the form `dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS.ssss`
- Each `id` number has two associated lines, a `START` line and an `END` line

What I want:

- Match up associated `START` & `END` lines
- Diff the timestamps
- Output to a file results like: `diffTime id`
- Output an error msg if `END` line doesn't appear after 1 minute.